# Yii2: Customized LoginForm is not working

Tags: php, yii2

I am writing my own login form to validate the user attempts.
Here is my code.

LoginForm.php:

```
namespace common\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use common\models\User;

class LoginForm extends Model{

    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $rememberMe = true;
    public $verification;

    private $user;

    public function rules(){
        return [
            [['username','password'],'trim'], 
            [['username','password'],'required','message'=>'Nothing Input Yet'],
            ['username','validateUsername'],
            ['rememberMe', 'boolean'],
            ];
    }

    public function validateUsername($attribute, $params){
        $user = User::find()->where(['username'=>$this->$attribute])->asArray()->one();
        if(!$user || md5($this->password)!=$user['password']){
                $this->addError($attribute,'Username/Password Error');
            }else{
                $this->user = $user;
            }
    } 
}
```

code for index:

```
<div class="container">
<?=Html::beginForm('','post',['enctype'=>'multipart/form-data','class'=>'form-signin'])?>

        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
        <?=Html::label('Username','username',['class'=>'sr-only'])?>
        <?=Html::input('text','username',$model->username,['id'=>'username','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Username','autofocus'=>true])?>
        <?=Html::error($model,'username',['class'=>'error'])?>
        <?=Html::label('Password','password',['class'=>'sr-only'])?>
        <?=Html::input('password','password',$model->password,['id'=>'inputPassword','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Password'])?>
        <?=Html::error($model,'password',['class'=>'error'])?>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
          </label>
        </div>
        <?=Html::submitButton('Login',['class'=>'btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block'])?>

<?=Html::endForm()?>
</div>
```

Here it is the LoginController.php

```
namespace backend\controllers;

use yii\web\Controller;
use common\models\LoginForm;
use Yii;


class LoginController extends Controller{

    public $layout = 'login' ;

    public function actionIndex(){

        $model = new LoginForm();

        if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()){
            return $this->redirect(['site/index']);
        }else{
            echo "bad";
        }

        return $this->render('index',['model'=>$model]);
    }

}
```

Now my problem is, no matter what I input or leave it blank, there is no respond after I submit the form. Only show the "bad" output.
I have checked all the code and couldn't find out where is wrong. Not even error message from the LoginForm model. Ex: 'Nothing Input Yet'.

ps: I found that there might be a way called exits but haven't tried yet, wanna fix my own code first the process next built-in method.

Attached the result output pic.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yii2 has a built-in method in user component for creating a user session called `login`. You can access that function by `Yii::$app->user->login($user)`.

Here is a your class with an extra method added.

```
// may be doing it after validating
namespace common\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use common\models\User;

class LoginForm extends Model{

 public $username;
 public $password;
 public $rememberMe = true;
 public $verification;

 private $user;

 public function rules(){
    return [
        [['username','password'],'trim'], 
        [['username','password'],'required','message'=>'Nothing Input Yet'],
        ['username','validateUsername'],
        ['rememberMe', 'boolean'],
        ];
 }

 public function validateUsername($attribute, $params){
    $user = User::find()->where(['username'=>$this->$attribute])->asArray()->one();
    if(!$user || md5($this->password)!=$user['password']){
            $this->addError($attribute,'Username/Password Error');
        }else{
            $this->user = $user;
        }
 } 
}

// adding this below method
public function login(){
 if($this->user && Yii::$app->user->login($this->user)) return true;
 return false;

}
```

And calling that new method in the controller.

```
if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate() && $model->login()){
        return $this->redirect(['site/index']);
}
```

**Note** Don't forget to add `User` class inside `user` component in config.

Comment: thanks for the code, just tried it and confirm the **User** components is enabled on the **config/main.php**, but the same result, no respond nor error message. but var_dump(...post()) can show the input.

Comment: Did you add login method to the class and also called in the controller?

Comment: Yes, but the same error, no output at all, just stuck at **scaisEdge** point that **$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())** seems to return false and cannot process next steps.

Answer (score 0):

check for `$model->validate()`
could be you have some problem with validation rules

```
  $model->load(\Yii::$app->request->post());

  if ($model->validate()) {
     var_dump('validation ok');

  } else {
      // validation failed: $errors is an array containing error messages
      $errors = $model->errors;
  }
```

try adding a safe for verification

```
public function rules(){
    return [
        [['username','password'],'trim'], 
        [['username','password'],'required','message'=>'Nothing Input Yet'],
        ['username','validateUsername'],
        ['rememberMe', 'boolean'],
        [['verification'], 'safe'],
        ];
}
```

Comment: hello, I just add your error code on the controller, and return an empty Array(). And I double check my Model, cannot find out any errors, can you help to find if there are any mistakes? Thank you.

Comment: try var_dump(\Yii::$app->request->post())   and check if the submitted valeue are ok

Comment: plus, I use Yii2 debug component to check and the page seems to submit the $_POST with correct input. But just no respond to redirect or error messages on output page.  **update**: use var_dump for the post() and indeed retrieve the input. however, still no output.

Comment: if you have "bad"  in your code  or you have problem in load(\Yii::$app->request->post()) or you have problem  with validate .. with the test on validate seem you have not validation problem ... the check if you have a proper $model populated with load .. try bar_dump($model)

Comment: yeah, you are right, the load() method returns false, but the $_post can get the input, do you know why it causes the issue?

Comment: Try adding a safe for verification in rule  .. i have update the answer .. (or could be related to the var private for $user)

Comment: sorry about late reply. just tried your suggestion and it is the same way, load() return false, no results displayed.

Comment: try  var_dump(\Yii::$app->request->post()) and check if the value returned matching the $model .. structure ..